# C# Chart.MarkerImage path error for UserControl

Tags: c#, charts, mfc

Sorry guys.Thanks Coming.

I have a strange error for that.

Now i use Windows Forms User Control in an MFC Dialog Box by msdn html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/94t3ebxz(v=vs.90).aspx

it's work and nice!

But i try to use the Chart.MarkerImage, it can't wrok;

(1)here is my project position

```
+project
    -Debug
    +MFCApplication
         -res
         -Debug
    +WindowsFormsControlLibrary
         -obj
         -Properties
         +Bin
             -Debug
```

(2)Here is UserControl1.Designer.cs

```
series.Points[m_nCurrentRecordPoints - 1].MarkerImage = "test.bmp";
```

First , when i set WindowsFormsControlLibrary as StartUp Project and put the test.bmp
into the \project\WindowsFormsControlLibrary\bin\Debug\test.bmp. Run this, it can show correct.

Question is here. I set MFCApplication as StartUp Project . wherever i put the test.bmp into.
it can't work!! 
 \project\Debug\test.bmp ? \project\WindowsFormsControlLibrary\bin\Debug\test.bmp ?
\project\MFCApplication\Debug\test.bmp ?

Thanks a lot!!

I want to use the relative path . Is Chart.MarkerImage possible to use BITMAP ?

Ps when i use the absolute path (EX: D:/test.bmp) , it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the module file path and construct a full path. (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
The code works only when the current directory is \project\WindowsFormsControlLibrary\bin\Debug, but even this setting may change during program execution.
Always try to use a full path for such resources,

Comment: That is very useful and interesting!! After i read your answer, i put the \project\Debug\MFCApplication1.exe into the \project\WindowsFormsControlLibrary\bin\Debug , and run the exe, it can work!! Thanks a lot !!!!!